# ADB not connecting after rooting with Magisk

Tags: adb, root-access, magisk

I rooted my Coolpad Modena 2 (E502) using Magisk. After I rebooted it, ADB stopped connecting.

Things I've tried:

- Wiping the phone and rooting it again
- Using different USBs

`adb devices` just shows "List of devices attached" and nothing else. USB debugging was turned on and I can connect fastboot but not adb. Also when selecting an option from the notification "Connected only for charging", it doesn't save the option, leaving it at the default Charging option.

**EDIT**: i managed to fix it by disabling factory mode.

Comment: What does `adb devices` show? Is the phone detected in MTP or USB tethering mode? This might sound silly but did you absolutely made certain that USB debugging was **not** turned off or did not get turned off in the time during which you performed the diagnosis?

Comment: `adb devices` just shows "List of devices attached" and nothing else and yes usb debugging was turned on and i can connect fastboot but not adb. Also when selecting a option from the notification "Connected only for charging" it dosn't save the option leaving it at the default Charging option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue is that when connecting the usb to the device adb dosn't connect to the phone, i can still charge it but i can't connect from adb to the phone. It shows me that the usb is connected on the device but adb just dosn't connect

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!